# extruding circular shape

Tags: modeling, transforms

How do you extrude a circular plane in two dimensions (e.g. z and y)?

I have a wheel with a tire. I have the rough animation of the wheel, but I cannot figure out how to extrude the tire in two dimensions. I've tried with extrude and scale combined but gives me the result seen in the picture.

[image: Quad view]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To scale in one plane, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ the axis you *don't* want to scale in.

For example, if you want to extrude and scale in the YZ plane, you would do <kbd>E</kbd>→<kbd>S</kbd>→<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

If you use the 3D Manipulator, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+clicking the handle of the axis you don't want to scale (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the X-axis handle for the YZ plane).

Comment: Wow that is useful! Learned something new already today :D